# How to change the color of the default title in iTerm2

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal, colors, iterm2

Every time I execute a command, it's difficult for me to find where is the start point of the results comes from my last command. So I want to make the default line "Arthur-Mac-mini..." change color, how can I do it?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: See [iTerm colors for Prompt, Command, and Output](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125637) and [How to Customize the Command Prompt](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-customize-the-command-prompt--net-20586)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I change the color of the default title in iTerm2

You can do this by modifying the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable.

The contents of this variable isn’t just a string, like with `PS1`. It’s actually a command that is executed before bash displays the prompt.

---

#### How to Customize the Command Prompt

> Customizing `PROMPT_COMMAND`
>
> The better way to do this is the use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable;
>   the contents of this variable isn’t just a string, like with `PS1`.
>   It’s actually a command that executed before bash displays the prompt.
>   To give this a try, let’s add this to our `.bashrc`:
>
> ```
> PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "comes before the prompt"'
> ```
>
> We’re using the `echo` command here; if you aren’t familiar with it,
>   you just pass it a string, and it will write it to the terminal. By
>   itself, it’s not incredibly useful (although you can use it to view
>   variables: `echo $PS1`), but it’s great when used with other commands,
>   so display their output.
>
> Let’s do something more useful here. Let’s write a bash function that
>   we will assign to `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Try this:
>
> ```
> print_before_the_prompt () {
>     echo "comes before the prompt"
> }
>
> PROMPT_COMMAND=print_before_the_prompt
> ```
>
> If you use this, you shouldn’t see a difference in your prompt from
>   what we have above. Now, let’s make this useful.
>
> ```
> print_before_the_prompt () {
>   echo "$USER: $PWD"
> }
>
> PROMPT_COMMAND=print_before_the_prompt
>
> PS1='->'
> ```

`print_before_the_prompt` is later modfied to add colour to the prompt.

...

> **Adding Some Color**
>
> Looking good! But let’s take it one step farther. Let’s add some color
>   to this. We can use some special codes to change the color of the text
>   in the terminal. It can be rather daunting to use the actual code, so
>   I like to copy this list of variables for the color and add it at the
>   top of my .bashrc file:
>
> ```
> txtblk='\e[0;30m' # Black - Regular
> txtred='\e[0;31m' # Red
> txtgrn='\e[0;32m' # Green
> txtylw='\e[0;33m' # Yellow
> txtblu='\e[0;34m' # Blue
> txtpur='\e[0;35m' # Purple
> txtcyn='\e[0;36m' # Cyan
> txtwht='\e[0;37m' # White
>
> bldblk='\e[1;30m' # Black - Bold
> bldred='\e[1;31m' # Red
> bldgrn='\e[1;32m' # Green
> bldylw='\e[1;33m' # Yellow
> bldblu='\e[1;34m' # Blue
> bldpur='\e[1;35m' # Purple
> bldcyn='\e[1;36m' # Cyan
> bldwht='\e[1;37m' # White
>
> unkblk='\e[4;30m' # Black - Underline
> undred='\e[4;31m' # Red
> undgrn='\e[4;32m' # Green
> undylw='\e[4;33m' # Yellow
> undblu='\e[4;34m' # Blue
> undpur='\e[4;35m' # Purple
> undcyn='\e[4;36m' # Cyan
> undwht='\e[4;37m' # White
>
> bakblk='\e[40m'   # Black - Background
> bakred='\e[41m'   # Red
> badgrn='\e[42m'   # Green
> bakylw='\e[43m'   # Yellow
> bakblu='\e[44m'   # Blue
> bakpur='\e[45m'   # Purple
> bakcyn='\e[46m'   # Cyan
> bakwht='\e[47m'   # White
>
> txtrst='\e[0m'    # Text Reset
> ```
>
> There’s some method to this madness: The first set are turn on normal
>   coloring. The second set turn on bold coloring. The third set turn on
>   underlined coloring. And that fourth set turn on background coloring.
>   That last one resets the coloring to normal. So, let’s use these!
>
> ```
> print_before_the_prompt () {
>     printf "\n $txtred%s: $bldgrn%s \n$txtrst" "$USER" "$PWD"
> }
> ```
>
> Here, I’ve added `$txtred` before the first `%s`, and `$bldgrn` before
>   the second `%s`; then, at the end, I’ve reset the text color. You have
>   to do this because once you set a color, it will hold until you either
>   use a new color or reset the coloring. You’ll also notice that when
>   setting a variable, we don’t prefix it with a dollar sign; but we do
>   use the dollar sign when using the variable: that’s the way bash
>   variables work. This gives us the following:
>
> [image]

Source [How to Customize the Command Prompt](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-customize-the-command-prompt--net-20586)